# Forma de leer los datos en Java enviado desde JavaScript Fetch API

Tags: javascript, java, fetch, servlets

Explico brevemente, necesito poder leer en un servlet Java los datos enviados desde una función `fetch()` de JavaScript, en el código dejo notas para más aclaración.

Me explico más en profundidad, en un fichero `.jsp` se crean una serie de input de tipo Checkbox, con un 'name' y un 'value', desde el fichero `.js`, se detecta, de manera individual, el cambio de un checkbox con un a función `addEventListener`, y dentro de la misma función se crea una función fetch() de JavaScript, ya en un objeto de datos con el 'name' y 'value' del checkbox que se ha cambiado se inserta en el fetch() y en la URL se llama a un Servlet de Java, por último, en dicho Servlet se pretende recoger la información que se ha enviado desde la función fetch de JavaScript, al hacerlo no salta ningun error, simplemente no soy capaz de como capturar dicha información enviada desde JavaScript, no se si esta mal la petición fetch() o que en el Servlet debo utilizar otras funciones.

**Fichero `index.jsp`**

```
<%@ page import="javax.websocket.RemoteEndpoint.Async"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
<%
List<String> butacas = new ArrayList<String>();
int ASCII_Init = 65;

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 9; j++) {      
        butacas.add((char)(ASCII_Init + i) + "0" + j);
    }
}
pageContext.setAttribute("butacas", butacas);
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Lookup Students</title>
         <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">         
    </head>

    <body class="container">
        <div id="content-btns" class="grid">
          <c:forEach var="butaca" items="${butacas}">
                <div class="form-check">
                  <!-- Cada vez que el input checkbox cambia se llama a la funcion fetch() en el fichero 'peticionesFetch.js' -->
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="${butaca}" name="${butaca}" id="cb-${butaca}">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="cb-${butaca}">
                    ${butaca}
                  </label>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
        <script src="js/peticionesFetch.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Fichero `peticionesFetch.js`**

```js
const contentBtns = document.getElementById("content-btns");

contentBtns.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  // Parametro 'name' es el identificador del input
  // Parametro 'value' indica si el input esta marcado o no

  if (e.target.tagName === "INPUT") {
    const name = e.target.value;
    const value = e.target.checked;

    // la idea principal era esta, pero no quiero utilizar las URL para enviar datos
    // const url = `marcarInput?name=${name}&value=${value}`;

    // lo que quiero es enviar los datos de la siguiente forma

    const url = 'marcarInput'; // URL del servlet de Java

    const data = {
      name : e.target.value,
      value : e.target.checked
    }

    const fetchData = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
      headers: new Headers()
    }

    fetch(url, fetchData)
      .then(function () {
        console.log("Todo ok");
        // otras funciones
      })
      .catch(function () {
        console.log("Todo mal");
        // control de errores
      });
  }
});
```

De esa forma esperaba enviar los datos al servet de Java, pero una vez en el servlet, no doy con el método para recuperarlos, a continuación dejo el código del servet.

Fcihero `marcarInput.java`

```java
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class pruebas
 */
@WebServlet("/marcarInput")
public class marcarInput extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // entiendo que request.getParameter("") no es el correcto pero he probado otras formas de hacerlo y siempre me devuelve NULL
    System.out.println("El input " + request.getParameter("name") + " esta marcado? " + request.getParameter("value")); 
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué hace el código actualmente? ¿Has depurado algo? ¿Con qué resultados? ¿Hay algún error? ¿Qué error? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedanoel codigo lo unico que hace es detectar que cada uno de los imputs checkbox, llama a la fucnion en JavaScript y dicho funcion (que usa API fetch) llama al servlet Java, y en dicho servlet se pretende capturar que input se ha cambiado y su valor, pero cuando llega al servlet se obtiene el valor NULL, no hay errores mas alla de ese

Comment: ¿En qué parte ves el `NULL`? ¿Depuraste por ejemplo `request`? ¿Tu Servlet no exige cabeceras para las peticiones?

Comment: @A.Cedano el `NULL` lo veo en el Servlet, a la hora de acceder al objeto request, y a sus diferentes parametros, pero no se si es porque me falta algo en la funcion `fetch()` JavaScript o estoy utilizando el metodo de Java erroneo.

Comment: Ya, pero ¿dónde lo ves, en el depurador, en la pantalla o donde? Convendría que revises el objeto en sí mismo, en el depurador, si es posible. Yo no he usado `fetch` con código Java, por lo que no sabría decirte exactamente si tu petición `fetch` está bien.

Comment: @A.Cedano el `NULL` lo veo en la consola de eclipse Java, cuando el Servlet es llamado y pretendo mostrar por la consola de Eclipse los datos enviados mediante la funcion fetch()

Comment: cuando usas `fetch` con `POST` necesitas enviar los datos en `body` como un string, así que si cambias `body: data,` con `body: JSON.stringify(data)`, probablemente te funcione. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#body

Comment: @Aguardientico y entonces para acceder a esos datos desde el Servlet de Java como deberia hacerlo? Ya que si utiliao el `getParameter()` me sigue dado `NULL`

Comment: @Javiluli.dev mi `java` y manejo de servlets está oxidado, podrías probar con `getParameterNames` para verificar qué parámetros vienen o con `getParameterMap` para obtener nombre/valor de los parámetros, verifica en los developer tools del navegador que la llamada envíe los parámetros como los esperas y que no mande algo como `[object Object]`

Comment: Pero conviene que examines el objeto en sí mismo, poniendo puntos de interrupción en el código, para que se detenga dentro del método y ahí **examinas los objetos**...  haciendo clic sobre ellos. No sé bien cómo funciona Eclipse, pero supongo que tiene maneras de debug como otros IDE donde puedes examinar los objetos. Así podrás ver si es el objeto en sí mismo el que viene nulo o si es que no estás usando el método adecuado para traer los datos. Lamentablemente no uso Java en programación del lado del servidor y no puedo hablarte con propiedad sobre qué métodos deberías usar o no.

Comment: @Aguardientico he probado ambos metodos y en ambos no recojo nada, pero al utilizar el `getContentType()` y si que me devuelve el que coloco en el `fetch()`, no se que me falta la verdad.

Comment: El primer paso es verificar si el browser está mandando los datos, verificaste eso? Según leo si usas cosas como `getReader` o `getInputStream` los parámetros dejan de estar disponibles en el servlet

Comment: Despues de varios dicas buscando info encontre la forma de obtener los datos en formato JSON en Java y de ahi transformalos con unba libreria llamada Gson, gracias por el consejo @Aguardientico, me fue muy util para buscar de otra forma la solucion al problema, saludos a todos.